# In Bluetooth LE, both GATT server and GATT client advertise before the connection is established?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am new to Bluetooth LE and working on a device from CSR,

1. Plan is to create a GATT client and GATT server.
2. Where GATT server can send data to GATT client using notifications.
3. But here, we want both server as well as client to be micro controller based BT LE devices.

Also, one more doubt is when GATT sever has data, is it the responsibility of the programmer to create and send a notification or is there some way that the notification is send automatically on updating the attribute.

Please provide if there is any example code available for this.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Also, is C the programming language you are using? Does the stack belong to CSR?

Comment: I am looking for an example code. Yes the stack is from CSR

Comment: Being server or client has nothing to do with advertising.

Answer (score 3):

The process actually goes like this:

1. The GATT server advertises.
2. The client is scanning; it sees the server and initiates a connection (where it becomes Master and the server is Slave).
3. The client finds the characteristic whose value it wants to be notified about.
4. The characteristic has a descriptor called CCCD (Client Characteristic Configuration descriptor) whose value it needs to modify accordingly in order to subscribe to notifications.
5. The GATT server sends notifications to the client because it has subscribed.